# Javascript dropdown menu onclick, (close others, when one is open)

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, slidetoggle

I have created a dropdown menu for a responsive website.
But I have a small problem. When I click the first menu tab, all tabs open.

`DEMO:` https://jsfiddle.net/vth4gn6w/2/

What I want:

1. When I click on the first tab, I want only that tab to open, without it activating the other tabs.
2. When I click on the second tab, I want the first tab to close automatically.

Hope somebody can help me, and plz use fiddle to show me how it's done. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to include the code as a snippet in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which element is being clicked? Not the entire `#nav-mobile`, but the `a`s inside. You want `#nav-mobile a` as your selector.

Now, where are the `ul`s in relation to their corresponding `a` (referred to as `$(this)` inside the callback function)? They are immediate siblings, so `$(this).next('ul')` is your best bet.

To close all the other menu items, save the the `ul` in a variable and use `.not()` to select the other `ul`s.

Your code should now look like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#nav-mobile a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $menuItem = $(this).next('ul');
        $menuItem.slideToggle();
        $('#nav-mobile ul').not($menuItem).slideUp();
    });
});
```

```css
#tab1, #tab2, #tab3{
  background-color:grey;
  color:white;
  padding:5px 10px;
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}

#tab1:hover, #tab2:hover, #tab3:hover{
  background-color:darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-mobile">
    <a href="#" id="tab1">Products</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Why Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="tab2">About</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li><a href="#">Our Equipment</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Video Production</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="tab3">Contact</a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li id="last-child"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li id="last-child"><a href="#">Social Media</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But when I try to close one of the tabs again, it opens automatically. Do you know how to fix that? @darrylyeo

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Glad to help! -

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix your js so it doesn't slide toggle the entire nav object.

https://jsfiddle.net/vth4gn6w/2/#&togetherjs=0vaEOk1NNT

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#nav-mobile ul').hide();
    $('#tab1').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#tab1ul').slideToggle();
    });

});
```

i setup the example for you for tab1 so when you click the first tab only the the menu which i created the id tab1ul expands. you can follow this as a guide to complete the functionality as you'd like it.